# Linked list function causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list

The purpose of this function is to be utilized for qsort function in the C library. The function below works only if the two sets have the same amount of elements. However, if one of the sets has less elements than the other set (and the values are continuously matching), my function seems to go into a segmentation fault. I believe the cause is that I'm recursively calling the next node when there might be a chance that the next node might be empty.

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    Node *pa = (Node*)a;
    Node *pb = (Node*)b;

    if (pa->val == pb->val)
        cmp( pa->next, pb->next );

    else if (pa->val < pb->val)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;

    return 0;  // placeholder
}
```

But I could be wrong, is the above function correct?

Comment: How about checking that neither `a` nor `b` is NULL? You also forgot to "return" the recursive `cmp` call:  `return cmp( pa->next, pb->next );`

Comment: Ah.. yes I was forgetting about that return statement.

Comment: What does this function do? As of now it will return only 0, after the NULL check and return statement is added

Comment: When I have two sets: A = {1 7 8} and B = {1 7 8 9}, the function should print out a "1" if A > B, else "-1" if B > A. Since set B has another element, then it should return -1 but I get 0 returned instead.

Comment: What is A > B? You mean the length?

Comment: So, from the above example, it should return -1, since set B has greater elements than set A (B > A). Vice versa

Comment: Check my edited answer. I have changed the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not at all checking if a node is NULL. You have to check it at the start of the function.

```
if(pa == NULL || pb == NULL)
    return 0;
```

Comment: I actually had that code, but I was returning NULL. But it makes sense to return 0 because then that means all the values are equal.

Comment: @Jase returning NULL is equivalent to returning 0.

Comment: I'm not trying to determine which has the shorter list. For example, if set A = {2, 7, 8} and set B = {1, 7, 8, 9}, then it will return 1 because the very first element in A is greater than first element in B.

Comment: Otherwise, if they keep matching, then I guess the largest set would be returning -1 (largest is set B) or 1(largest is set A).

Comment: @Jase: Then I think the above NULL condition alone should be added to your code to suffice.. And the return statement at cmp call

Comment: I actually got the code working to the output I wanted. Thanks for your help thus far.